# Get data by time from FIrebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is data at firebase

[image]

i want to get future data like this:

```
ref.where("startTime", ">", new Date()))
```

but it isn't working

i try this:

```
ref.where("startTime.seconds", ">", Date.now() / 1000))
```

but it still doesn't. i have no idea for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
ref().child("Users").orderByChild('startTime').startAt("2022-01-05").endAt("2029-01-10");
```

Comment: its only used by fbadmin ??? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: i do not thing so, I've tried but the user must login first. i try in flutter dev but i think its same

Comment: In react-native project: 

I am using firebase like this:

`firestore().collection("carry").orderByChild`

the `orderByChild` doesn't exist

Comment: hmm. try see here https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage. maybe its can help

Answer (score 0):

```js
const startfulldate = firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

ref.where("startTime", ">", startfulldate)
```

It's working.   :)